# Jquery ajax - ignore non-json data in response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have message form that has to work both with javascript and without.

With js it woudl send data by ajax. PHP woudl be returning status info (success/failure) encoded in json.

Without js form works as regular form, except that it needs status messages returned in plaintext (no way to parse json into human redable form without js). But if i try to return json data along with plaintext i will get error because of   dataType    : 'json' setting.

Can i just ignoe non json data if js is disabled and display onli plaintext without js enabled?

Comment: AJAX can work with a plain string as a response; set `dataType: 'text'` to prevent jQuery from trying to parse it.

Comment: The best solutions will be to use a seperate server side url for the two different actions (ajax, or regular post).
Otherwise, you can use a POST param to test the difference

Comment: Which server side language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i actually got it. I just sticked to detecting on php side if there is ajax request, depending on that i return json or plaintext.

I detect ajax by

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'))
```